# Spring Boot + Jetty ClosedChannelException

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-jetty

I'm seeing often the following exception in the logs:

```
2019-07-03 02:56:43.750 ERROR 19242 --- [qtp1725165248-1671] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][qtp1725165248-1671] Exception processing template "receiver": An error happened during template rendering

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateOutputException: An error happened during template rendering
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.OutputTemplateHandler.handleText(OutputTemplateHandler.java:75) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleText(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:587) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.Text.beHandled(Text.java:97) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:592) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1371) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1117) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1056) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645) [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar!/:4.0.1]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar!/:4.0.1]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:876) [jetty-servlet-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623) [jetty-servlet-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:214) [websocket-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) [jetty-servlet-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.DoSFilter.doFilterChain(DoSFilter.java:482) [jetty-servlets-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.DoSFilter.doFilter(DoSFilter.java:327) [jetty-servlets-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.DoSFilter.doFilter(DoSFilter.java:297) [jetty-servlets-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) [jetty-servlet-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at com.example.InternalSecurityFilter.doFilter(InternalSecurityFilter.java:54) [classes!/:1.49.2]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) [jetty-servlet-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) [jetty-servlet-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) [jetty-servlet-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) [jetty-servlet-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) [jetty-servlet-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540) [jetty-servlet-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146) [jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) [jetty-security-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257) [jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711) [jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255) [jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347) [jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203) [jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480) [jetty-servlet-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678) [jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201) [jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249) [jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144) [jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505) [jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370) [jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267) [jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305) [jetty-io-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) [jetty-io-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:427) [jetty-io-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:321) [jetty-io-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:159) [jetty-io-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) [jetty-io-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117) [jetty-io-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333) [jetty-util-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310) [jetty-util-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168) [jetty-util-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126) [jetty-util-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366) [jetty-util-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781) [jetty-util-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917) [jetty-util-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateOutputException: An error happened during template rendering (template: "receiver" - line 320, col 5)
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.OutputTemplateHandler.handleText(OutputTemplateHandler.java:75) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleText(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:587) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.Text.beHandled(Text.java:97) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.process(TemplateManager.java:519) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.util.LazyProcessingCharSequence.writeUnresolved(LazyProcessingCharSequence.java:85) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.util.AbstractLazyCharSequence.write(AbstractLazyCharSequence.java:103) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.AbstractTextualTemplateEvent.writeContent(AbstractTextualTemplateEvent.java:224) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.Text.write(Text.java:78) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.OutputTemplateHandler.handleText(OutputTemplateHandler.java:71) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.isOpen(ResponseWriter.java:133) ~[jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.write(ResponseWriter.java:230) ~[jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.write(ResponseWriter.java:248) ~[jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.AbstractTextualTemplateEvent.writeContent(AbstractTextualTemplateEvent.java:218) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.Text.write(Text.java:78) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.OutputTemplateHandler.handleText(OutputTemplateHandler.java:71) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        ... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.onClose(WriteFlusher.java:492) ~[jetty-io-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.onClose(AbstractEndPoint.java:353) ~[jetty-io-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.doOnClose(AbstractEndPoint.java:225) ~[jetty-io-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.close(AbstractEndPoint.java:192) ~[jetty-io-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
```

I found that there is not much to do when a `ClosedChannelException` is thrown, so I'm not sure why the exception is logged as ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your thymeleaf library attempted to write to a connection that was closed already.

You might have an indication earlier in your logs (for the same thread id and/or connection id) that the connection was closed, likely via a normal servlet and/or HTTP event.